# React js server side rendering tutorials

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I've learned basics of React js, so I can create web pages, also I practiced node js with express. And now my problem is to work with server side rendering. There are a lot of tutorials, but unfortunately all of them shows very different ways to work with SSR, or I just got confused with it :). Even some steps are so old that I got many errors after I've done.

With that I would be happy if you would show me or leave the links of the steps and right way to work with SSR from scratch where I can do with last versions.

Thank you for your understanding!!!

Comment: You can use Next.js, And use handlebars or ejs or pug any template engines in express.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to take a look at https://nextjs.org/.

Next.js is the best way to do SSR with React.js

Comment: But won't it slow the loading process